# Typescript library for SVG

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I've been using Raphael with an Angular 4 app and also tried to switch to Snap.  Neither of these support typescript very well (at all?).

Does anyone know of a library that includes full typescript types and doesn't require a PhD to get it working with Angular2/4/5?

If not, I'm thinking I will create a pure typescript library but that's a lot of work.

Comment: Could you share please, how did you make Raphael working with Angular 4?

Comment: I didnt use the types as they are not up to date with the latest version.  I sort of got it working but in the end we decided to switch to canvas and Im using FabricJS.  It's better for out needs but still has some small issues - documentation is not the best but there are plenty of experts and resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just install the `@types` package for Raphael.

It is maintained by the TypeScript community. These are people who like yourself, write apps in TypeScript and use Raphael.

If you find that the declarations are imperfect, you can open an issue (or a pull request) on https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Installation:

With NPM:

```
$ npm install --save @types/raphael
```

With JSPM:

```
$ jspm install npm:@types/raphael
```

With Yarn:

```
$ yarn add @types/raphael
```

Usage:

```
import Raphael from 'raphael';
```

The same applies to snapsvg

Comment: Ive switched to Snap and this seems to work better now.  Cheers!

Comment: Actually, now I have the dredded "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined" error.  I'll post a new question for this....

Comment: @Jonesie it's probably just a module format issue or a loader issue. Try `import Raphael = require('raphael');`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735087/snap-svg-with-typescript-and-webpack-error-cannot-read-property-on-of-undefin

Comment: I cant use require :( :  Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.