# Snap SVG with Typescript and Webpack error "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, snap.svg

I have an Angular 4 app using Snap SVG and I get the dredded webpack problem "Cannot read property 'on' of undefined".

Using snapsvg-cjs seems to be the simplest way to fix this but then I lose all the nice typescript typings (answered here: [Typescript library for SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724872/typescript-library-for-svg)).

There is some talk of using import-loader but then I would need a web pack config and angular cli takes that away.  Plus :

`import Snap from 'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0!snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js';`

doesn't compile in typescript.

Im pretty new to all this stuff so am feeling somewhat confused - I wish I was back doing VB6 on windows again.... :).  Can anyone clarify this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see what I did now.  Using snapsvg-cjs just works.  I get typescript support.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. For me, I installed `snapsvg-cjs` and `@types/snapsvg`, then imported the library as so:

```
import "snapsvg-cjs"
```

You only need to import it this way once (maybe in a `main.ts` file or something)

Then in the file where you want to use the library, import the types as so:

```
import * as SNAPSVG_TYPE from "snapsvg"
declare var Snap: typeof SNAPSVG_TYPE
```

This allowed me to use the typescript types like normal while still employing the webpack compatible version.

Comment: Weve since switched to using the canvas via FabricJS.  Working well for us.'