# how to use Snap.svg plugins (Snap.svg.zpd) with typescript and webpack 4

Tags: javascript, typescript, svg, webpack, snap.svg

#### Hello everyone.

Am starting a new project (web app) wish require me to use the [**Snap.svg**](http://snapsvg.io) library along with the [**zpd**](https://github.com/hueitan/snap.svg.zpd) plugin (A zoom/pan/drag plugin for Snap.svg) from https://github.com/hueitan/snap.svg.zpd.
so am using [**Typescript**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) as the mains coding language along with [**webpack 4**](https://webpack.js.org/) as bundling solution (am new to both of these) .
I managed including Snap.svg in this environment using modified version of Snap.svg :[**Snap.svg-cjs**](https://github.com/geelen/Snap.svg-cjs) (duo to some problems encountered when using the official Snap.svg with webpack (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735087/snap-svg-with-typescript-and-webpack-error-cannot-read-property-on-of-undefin)) ) along  [**type definitions for Snap.svg**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/snapsvg) (just renaming the folder under PathToNodeModules/@types/snapsvg to "snapsvg-cjs" seems to work just fine)

#### And now am having another problem including the zpd plugin into the project (Typescript)

The problem seems to be duo to the missing  type definitions for that plugin, so can anyone please help me on how to write those typings or maybe provide a workaround  to include snap.svg plugins in Typescript projects without writing the typings

```
import * as Snap from "snapsvg-cjs";
import  {Paper} from "snapsvg-cjs";
//TODO : include the zpd plugin

let p:Paper;
p= Snap("snap") 
p.circle(100,100,50)
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone facing the same problem you just need to make your own "type definitions"  for that plugins .
here is how i did it :

```
import * as Snap from 'snapsvg-cjs';
//or  import * as Snap from 'snap.svg'; 
//if you are using the official version of snap.svg

declare module  'snapsvg-cjs' {
   interface  Paper{

       zpd (options?:any, callbackFunc?:(nan:null,zpdelement:any)=>void):void
       zoomTo(zoom:number, interval?:number, ease?:(num:number)=>number, callbackFunction?:(nan:null,zpdelement:any)=>void):void;
       panTo(x:string|number, y:string|number, interval?: number, ease?:(num:number)=>number, cb?:(nan:null,zpdelement:any)=>void):void;
       rotate(a:number,x?:number, y?:number, interval?: number, ease?:(num:number)=>number, cb?:(nan:null,zpdelement:any)=>void):void;
   }
}
```