# Raphael with Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, raphael

I am trying to add [Raphael](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael) to an Angular 4+ project. I have no idea where to start. Ideally I would want it added with types and all. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724872/typescript-library-for-svg) but not managed to get it working.

A step by step guide using the angular CLI would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step guide to setup a sample project with Angular + Raphael with types.

1. Create an angular project using angular CLI `ng new raphael-sampel`
2. Install Raphael in project `npm install raphael`
3. Install Raphael types `npm install --save @types/raphael`
4. Replace HTML content in app.component.html with `<div id="paper"></div>`
5. Import Raphael into app.component.ts `import * as Raphael from 'raphael';`
6. Implement OnInit in app.component.ts (see below)

   `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
      import * as Raphael from 'raphael';`

   @Component({
         selector: 'app-root',
         templateUrl: './app.component.html',
         styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
      })
      export class AppComponent implements OnInit
      {
        ngOnInit(): void 
        {
           let paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('paper'), 500, 500);
           paper.circle(100, 100, 100).attr({'fill':'270-#FAE56B:0-#E56B6B:100'});
        }
      }